# PostgreSQL Performance Issues in Docker After Migrating Diango 2.0.1 Application to New Server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I'm experiencing issues after migrating my Django application from an old server to a new one, with the application now running in Docker. Below is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  way_db:
    image: postgres:10
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=ways
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=********
      - POSTGRES_DB=ways_db
      - PGPORT=5432

  railway_redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  railway_web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8888 priv_project.wsgi:application
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - railway_db
      - railway_redis
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=railway_db
      - DATABASE_NAME=railways_db
      - DATABASE_USER=railways
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=*********
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=priv_project.settings.production

  railway_celery_worker:
    build: .
    command: celery -A priv_project worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - railway_db
      - railway_redis
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=priv_project.settings.production
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://railway_redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://railway_redis:6379/0

  railway_celery_beat:
    build: .
    command: /bin/sh -c "rm -f /app/celerybeat.pid && celery -A priv_project beat --loglevel=info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - railway_db
      - railway_redis
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=priv_project.settings.production
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://railway_redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://railway_redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BEAT_PID_FILE=/app/celerybeat.pid

  railway_backup_app:
    build: ./backups_railway
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Almaty
      - BACKUP_TIME=23:00  # backup time in 24h format
      - BACKUP_RETENTION_DAYS=30 # how many days to keep backups
      - HOME=/app
      - LOG_BACKUPS_COUNT=30
      - LOG_BACKUPS_SIZE_BYTES=2000000
    volumes:
      - ./backups_railway:/app

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I'm facing periodic database performance issues, such as:

```sql
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.354 UTC [35388] ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.354 UTC [35388] STATEMENT:  SELECT "app_appwaybooking"."id", "app_appwaybooking"."trv_order_id", "app_appwaybooking"."access_code", "app_appwaybooking"."order_id", "app_appwaybooking"."express_id", "app_appwaybooking"."date_departure", "app_appwaybooking"."time_departure", "app_appwaybooking"."from_station", "app_appwaybooking"."to_station", "app_appwaybooking"."passengers_num", "app_appwaybooking"."service_fee", "app_appwaybooking"."partner_fee", "app_appwaybooking"."amount", "app_appwaybooking"."serialized_data", "app_appwaybooking"."created", "app_appwaybooking"."updated", "app_appwaybooking"."is_paid", "app_appwaybooking"."payment_id", "app_appwaybooking"."payment_method", "app_appwaybooking"."email", "app_appwaybooking"."phone", "app_appwaybooking"."status", "app_appwaybooking"."user_id", "app_appwaybooking"."die_at", "app_appwaybooking"."is_transit", "app_appwaybooking"."serialized", "app_appwaybooking"."owner", "app_appwaybooking"."partner_account_id", "app_appwaybooking"."platform" FROM "app_appwaybooking" WHERE ("app_appwaybooking"."partner_account_id" = 440 AND "app_appwaybooking"."status" = 'ISSUED') ORDER BY "app_appwaybooking"."created" DESC
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.354 UTC [35389] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.354 UTC [35389] STATEMENT:  SELECT "app_appwaybooking"."id", "app_appwaybooking"."trv_order_id", "app_appwaybooking"."access_code", "app_appwaybooking"."order_id", "app_appwaybooking"."express_id", "app_appwaybooking"."date_departure", "app_appwaybooking"."time_departure", "app_appwaybooking"."from_station", "app_appwaybooking"."to_station", "app_appwaybooking"."passengers_num", "app_appwaybooking"."service_fee", "app_appwaybooking"."partner_fee", "app_appwaybooking"."amount", "app_appwaybooking"."serialized_data", "app_appwaybooking"."created", "app_appwaybooking"."updated", "app_appwaybooking"."is_paid", "app_appwaybooking"."payment_id", "app_appwaybooking"."payment_method", "app_appwaybooking"."email", "app_appwaybooking"."phone", "app_appwaybooking"."status", "app_appwaybooking"."user_id", "app_appwaybooking"."die_at", "app_appwaybooking"."is_transit", "app_appwaybooking"."serialized", "app_appwaybooking"."owner", "app_appwaybooking"."partner_account_id", "app_appwaybooking"."platform" FROM "app_appwaybooking" WHERE ("app_appwaybooking"."partner_account_id" = 440 AND "app_appwaybooking"."status" = 'ISSUED') ORDER BY "app_appwaybooking"."created" DESC
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.354 UTC [35390] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.354 UTC [35390] STATEMENT:  SELECT "app_appwaybooking"."id", "app_appwaybooking"."trv_order_id", "app_appwaybooking"."access_code", "app_appwaybooking"."order_id", "app_appwaybooking"."express_id", "app_appwaybooking"."date_departure", "app_appwaybooking"."time_departure", "app_appwaybooking"."from_station", "app_appwaybooking"."to_station", "app_appwaybooking"."passengers_num", "app_appwaybooking"."service_fee", "app_appwaybooking"."partner_fee", "app_appwaybooking"."amount", "app_appwaybooking"."serialized_data", "app_appwaybooking"."created", "app_appwaybooking"."updated", "app_appwaybooking"."is_paid", "app_appwaybooking"."payment_id", "app_appwaybooking"."payment_method", "app_appwaybooking"."email", "app_appwaybooking"."phone", "app_appwaybooking"."status", "app_appwaybooking"."user_id", "app_appwaybooking"."die_at", "app_appwaybooking"."is_transit", "app_appwaybooking"."serialized", "app_appwaybooking"."owner", "app_appwaybooking"."partner_account_id", "app_appwaybooking"."platform" FROM "app_appwaybooking" WHERE ("app_appwaybooking"."partner_account_id" = 440 AND "app_appwaybooking"."status" = 'ISSUED') ORDER BY "app_appwaybooking"."created" DESC
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.364 UTC [1] LOG:  worker process: parallel worker for PID 35388 (PID 35389) exited with exit code 1
app-master-appway_db-1             | 2023-11-22 16:49:00.375 UTC [1] LOG:  worker process: parallel worker for PID 35388 (PID 35390) exited with exit code 1
app-master-appway_web-1            | [2023-11-22 16:49:00 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:102)
app-master-appway_web-1            | [2023-11-22 22:49:00 +0600] [102] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 102)
app-master-appway_web-1            | [2023-11-22 16:49:01 +0000] [108] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 108
```

These errors occur when attempting to execute a large SQL query through Django ORM. I've tried changing the statement_timeout to 10 seconds, but it didn't resolve the issue. Interestingly, the query executes in 2 seconds locally, but fails on the server.

The server specs are 4 GB RAM and 4 CPU, similar to the old server. I suspect the issue might be related to Docker settings. Does anyone have experience with similar problems or suggestions for Docker settings to improve PostgreSQL performance?

Thank you for your help!

p.s. i try and set statement_timeout on all database:

```py
    'OPTIONS': {
        'options': '-c statement_timeout=5000' # Here
     }
```

i want to know whats going on (: